# How to transfer data between Aramdillo matrix and LibTorch tensor?

Tags: c++, armadillo, libtorch

I am trying to transfer data between Aramdillo matrix and LibTorch tensor.

I referenced [this project](https://github.com/andrewssobral/dtt), but the conversion failed in my Linux environment.

Then I tried to convert using the `from_blob` interface provided by libtorch and it still failed.

Here is my code.

```cpp
arma::mat matrix{{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9}};
cout << "armadillo matrix: \n";
cout << matrix << endl;
auto t = torch::from_blob(matrix.memptr(), {2, 3});
cout << "libtorch tensor: \n";
cout << t << endl
```

Here is the output.

```
armadillo matrix:
   1.0000   2.0000   3.0000
   7.0000   8.0000   9.0000

libtorch tensor:
 0.0000  1.8750  0.0000
 2.4375  0.0000  2.0000
[ CPUFloatType{2,3} ]
```

Transfer data between Aramdillo matrix and LibTorch tensor.

Comment: Please don't paste text as images. Why would you paste the code as text but not the output??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does `torch::from_blob()` require 32 bit or 64 bit floating point data?  If it's 32 bit float, the armadillo matrix type should be `arma::fmat`, not `arma::mat`.  The  `arma::fmat` type is equivalent to [`arma::Mat<float>`](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat).

Comment: Thank you! I got it!
Firstly, we should transpose the matrix `matrix = matrix.t()`, then we can transfer it like this: `auto t = torch::from_blob(matrix.memptr(), {2, 3}, torch::kFloat64)`.